# How to combine strings in one DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am processing inbound user data. I receive `DataFrame` `h` that is supposed to contain all `float` but has some strings:

```
>>> h = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> h.loc[0, 'a'] = 'bad'
>>> h.loc[1, 'b'] = 'robot'
>>> h
           a           b
0        bad    0.747314
1   0.921919       robot
2   0.754256    0.664455
```

I process and set the strings to `np.nan` (I realize `np.nan` is a `float` but this is to illustrate):

```
>>> hh = h.copy()
>>> hh.loc[0, 'a'] = np.nan
>>> hh.loc[1, 'b'] = np.nan
>>> hh
           a           b
0        NaN    0.747314
1   0.921919         NaN
2   0.754256    0.664455
```

I have a `DataFrame` with expected values (or a `dict`):

```
>>> g = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo'], 'b': ['bar']}, index=h.index)
>>> g
      a       b
0   foo     bar
1   foo     bar
2   foo     bar
```

Which I use to fill where the bad data is.

```
>>> hh.fillna(g)
          a           b
0        foo    0.747314
1   0.921919         bar
2   0.754256    0.664455
```

I need to include the *expected* data too. So the result should be:

```
>>> magic(hh, g)
                   a                     b
0   rec=bad; exp=foo              0.747314
1           0.921919    rec=robot; exp=bar
2           0.754256              0.664455
```

How can I create such a result?

Comment: can't you create `g` with expected results ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert non necessary values to `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), join together with `string`s and last replace original values:

```
m = hh.isna()
df = ('rec=' + h.where(m) + '; exp=' + g.where(m)).fillna(h)
print (df)
                  a                   b
0  rec=bad; exp=foo            0.440508
1          0.525949  rec=robot; exp=bar
2          0.337586            0.414336
```

Comment: This answer is a clean piece of code. @jezrael I honestly miss a `Q&A` about `.where` function of pandas. I mostly use `np.where` since I understand it better. Would you consider writing one?

Comment: @Erfan - Hmmm, I think better is ask coldspeed, now cs95 for it - he is better expert for such answers. But thank you.